# Do Web Services create overhead if not required?

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller, architecture, project

We are developing an mvc web application and UI will be responsive, so don’t see any future requirement with web services required for native app that will consume services. However if we want to use Angular js in the future on the client side then yes it is required.

Now the questions is:

Will the performance better in case we use project libraries (Service library not web api) instead of using REST services created in Web api? Or there will not be much difference if we use rest services?

I believe including reference of service project libraries would be the best option if rest services are not required. As when request from client goes to server it don’t need another http request for calling rest services.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Correct, do you ever came across such scenario? Or do you have any facts/reference for the correct answer?

Comment: What is your question here? You are building native apps that will use the dlls directly, and you want to know if you still need the apis?

Comment: My advice is to go for the reference of service project libraries. Of course it will be faster than creating an API, adding a security layer (for instance OAuth2.0) to enable only allowed users to consume your web services, just to name a few extra task you would have to do. The good thing is, if in a few months you need to create an API, you just have to create a web API project and reference it as well to your service project libraries (remember, all of your business logic must be encapsulates in your service project libraries, not your controllers).

Comment: Thanks wilsotobianco, You are correct however as Epodax mentioned, its entirely based on opinion. Do you have any facts/reference for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The best of both worlds would be including reference of service project libraries, *but* designing them in a way where you can have a very thin layer - an ApiController - to just handle the WebService security, if any, and call the logic.

If you do it right, the controller should have next to no code aside from calling your service classes.

Other advantage: you can implement a couple of those controllers exposing your services as REST services, just to prove that you got the gist of it and that your architecture works, and then, at a later date, expose all the other services as RESTful API as you need them, when you switch to AngularJS for instance.

Comment: This may prove troublesome if you build your code against the service classes. There can be serialization issues (circular references, non-serializable classes) that you won't notice until you try to serve them from the webservice.

Comment: I'm not sure how circular references could happen in that case, but you have a point regarding the fact that one choose wisely the types to expose in the objects returned by those services, otherwise, more code will be required to make sure they can be serialized.

Comment: Circular references are created easily, for example by returning an `Order` with a `List<OrderLine>` property, where `OrderLine` has a reference back to `Order`. This will work fine with an assembly reference, but not through serialization without changes.

Comment: Oh, good point. One should be extra careful when designing the returned objects then.

Answer (score 1):

Web services have an overhead proportional to the number of calls. Measure it by calling a no-op service 100000 times. You probably get 1000-5000 calls per second per CPU core.

This measure does not include network latency.

Depending on how chatty your app is the perf cost can be near zero or devastating.

When adding a web service layer the biggest concern usually is productivity cost. It is significant. You can no longer share objects between layers and rely on object identity. Everything is copied. No ORM use on the client for example.

Web services are not something you add lightly. Maybe you can architect your code as a library that is later amenable to be put into a web service as well. But that's hard thanks to the rather fundamental problem that state cannot be shared.